# Error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Forbidden. Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I am having this error. I got it when I downloaded a basic template of a bot on azure. Then i copied its keys and credentials to my old bot then publish my old bot to the slot of bot template i downloaded. How to resolve this?

[image]

and
[image]

Comment: Well start with the first obvious error.. "request to send auth toekn to untrusted domain" only a fixed set of domains should be configured to receive auth tokens" ..  Also read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to get better answers

Comment: I'm sorry i can read that but i don't know where to start. I am new to azure and web.

Comment: Did your old bot work on your local environment?

Comment: @TonyJu Yes sir it is working fine on bot emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#publish-c-bot-on-app-service-plan-from-visual-studio). This document has been updated recently.

The key point is that you need to update your local appsettings.json or .env file with the one in the source code you downloaded from azure portal. Then update your local bot code.

**Startup.cs**

In the `ConfigureServices` method, use the configuration object that ASP.NET Core provides.

```
var appId = Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftAppId").Value;
var appPassword = Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftAppPassword").Value;
options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(appId, appPassword);
```

Comment: It published the old bot successfully but still receive the forbidden error when testing in web chat.

Comment: @user10860402 I used the web app bot which I created a month ago, it works fine. The new one doesn't work. I will do further research regarding this.

Comment: @user10860402 I have figured it out. The document indeed has been changed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Have you managed to make your new bot work? i will try this sir.

Comment: @user10860402 Yes, it works. The document is different from a month ago. I followed the new document and it works well.

Comment: In order for me to make the bot emulator works i need to remove the 3 new lines in startup.cs. But to publish i need to put it back. Is it the same with you?

Comment: @user10860402 It depends on your code, you can change the code to make both of them work. But I am not familiar with the code. You can find something like var environment = _isProduction ? "production" : "development";

Comment: Sorry for asking i have that line what should i do with it?

Comment: @user10860402 Since 'HTTP status code Forbidden' has been answered. And to avoid extended discussions in comments which are not related to this topic, can you post a new question?

Comment: Yes sir here it is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646534/cannot-post-activity-unauthorize-bot-emulator-error

Answer (score 0):

Did you set domain specific authentication layer in your channels configuration?
These are something you can try
[Check this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1729) and [This one](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/),especially point (5)

I hope it helps!